# A question on 1 form

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

If $d\,\sigma=0$ and $\sigma$ is non trivially with basis' coefficient 0, then $\sigma$ is a exterior derivative of a scalar function. I knew $d^{2} =0$. So it seems that all I am quoting is that $d^{2}f=0$ for $f$ being a scalar function. I do not see this as a proof.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms) Wikipedia page seems relevant.

Comment: a proof of what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your implications confused. A form $\sigma$ is *closed* if $d\, \sigma = 0$. A form  $\sigma$ is *exact* if $\sigma = df$. The statement that $d^2 = 0$ is the same as that *every exact form is closed*. The opposite is not true in general, there are many cases where a closed form is not exact. The existence of forms that are closed but not exact depends on the topology of the space involved.

However, *locally* every closed form is exact. By this I mean that for a point $p$, and a closed form $\sigma$, we can find a neighborhood $U$ containing $p$, and a form $f$, such that *on $U$*, $\sigma = df$. This can be done by taking a coordinate system around $p$ and letting $U$ be a ball in these coordinates. On a ball every closed form is exact.

Even though this can always be done around a point, it may be the case that it can not be done consistently, so that no single $f$, defined everywhere, satisfies $df = \sigma$.

Comment: I would say the space is path connected so that every closed path can be contracted to a point. From this, every closed path is homotopic to a point. This deduces that the form is exact globally.

Comment: I think you want simply connected, not path connected. A circle is certainly path connected but it supports non-exact closed forms.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that.